# datepicker doesn't work in ie7

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have implemented a ui datepicker which works perfectly in FF but not in IE.

See here [link](http://mbvdoornedu.cursistennet.nl/aanmelden/aanmelden) try to click on the "Geboortedatum" field.
What's going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is your problem:

```
    //set the rules for the field names
            rules: {
                firstname: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                surname: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },              
                email:{
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                password:{
                    required: true
                }, <----- remove this comma !!!

            },
```

remove that comma above. also, if you put that block of code into http://jslint.com you will find out the same thing. IE does not like trailing commas like that in hashes, as others have pointed out

Comment: +1 spotted the good comma, nice one!

Answer (score 2):

Line 76 - 78 in Ladosa.js:

```
password:{
  required: true,
},
```

should be

```
password:{
  required: true
},
```

At least that's what my IE is giving errors about.

Hope this helps you in the right direction.

**EDIT** (line 78, also in Ladosa.js)

```
rules: { //begin rules tag
  ...

  password:{
    required: true
  }, // <--- remove this comma also!

}, //end rules tag

messages: {
    name: "Please enter your name",
    email: "Please enter a valid email address"
},
```

Be sure to check if all opening tags have closing tags, and when removing code in a function please be sure to remove everything...
Also if you INDENT (*code laten inspringen*) your code it is easier to spot the mistake.

Comment: how are you able to see line 79, my view source only shows to line 69 for some reason

Comment: I edited the answer: it's line 76-78 in Ladosa.js.

Comment: no...my question is for viewing the source code, when I open it in notepad, the farthest the line goes to is 69 and i dont understand why